# SQLAlchemy database session not being removed after web request

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, database-connection

I'm using SQLAlchemy in my Flask app, and after a few requests have been made the app fails, with this error emitted:
`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at ..., port 5432 failed: FATAL:  too many connections for role "..."`. I then have to restart the  app to get it working again.

It seems as though with each web request, a database connection is being created but not removed. I can't figure out why that is, as I've added `scoped_session.remove()` to an `@app.teardown_request` function.

Here is my code...

app.py

```
...
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    global database
    database = PostgreSQL()

@app.teardown_request
def teardown(response):
    database.session.remove()
...
```

PostgreSQL.py

```
class PostgreSQL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.database_url = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
        if self.database_url.startswith('postgres://'):
            self.database_url = self.database_url.replace('postgres://', 'postgresql://')
        self.engine = create_engine(self.database_url, echo = False)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine, checkfirst = True)
        self.session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind = self.engine))
...
```

I guess I'd never have run into this problem if I used Flask-SQLAlchemy (which appears to handle things like database sessions for you) from the outset, but I'm keen to follow this problem through without resorting to that additional layer of abstraction - so please refrain from mentioning that module, unless it really is the only viable option here.

EDIT: Figured out the problem - needed to call `database.engine.dispose()` in `@app.teardown_request`

Comment: Good to see you found a solution. It's not an ideal solution as it's quite expensive to make the engine, setup the metadata and create a session just to dispose of it after one web request. If you haven't already read it, go over SQLAlchemy's FAQ on the [Session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#session-frequently-asked-questions). In essence 1) setup your database connection and sessionmaker **once** in your app & 2) when needed create a database session.

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your question. You can post an answer to your own question